# No matching version found

Tags: javascript

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for tagcloud@^2.0.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

But  "TagCloud"  is in package.json.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "TagCloud": "^2.0.2"}

Comment: npm commands are not case-sensitive？

Comment: dependencies is a list of packages required. It does not mean that you can find them in the repositories that you are currently linked to

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is, if the `npm install` command doesn't work, to run `npm i -S TagCloud@2.0.2` if you need to use that specific version, otherwise, just run `npm i -S TagCloud`.